# Set multiple session and return value from them

Tags: php

I want to set multiple session with multiple values. Then I want to call them by their name or id. Please check the code bellow i am getting output of:

```
Notice: Undefined index: foo1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\test.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined index: foo2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\test.php on line 12
```

How can set return value something like: `foo1 => val_01, foo2 => val_02`
is that really possible with php session functions?

```
<?php
$_SESSION['foo1']= 'val_01';
$_SESSION['foo2']= 'val_02';

session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['foo1']);
print_r($_SESSION['foo2']);
?>
```

Comment: you need to first start the session before you "write to it".

Comment: As @Jeff suggests, you cannot use a session, neither read nor write to one, before starting the session. `session_start();` is often suggested to be included as the first line of your php code.  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: code formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code bellow. You need to start session first to write on it.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo1']= 'val_01';
$_SESSION['foo2']= 'val_02';


print_r($_SESSION['foo1']);
print_r($_SESSION['foo2']);
?>
```